# Limit the view for Role so Only see Accounts in their branch of the hierarchy

Tags: person-accounts, role-hierarchy

Can I limit the View for ROLE APAC so that they only see APAC accounts and not AMER.

Comment: Do you have the account users in a Role Hierarchy? If so you can use the Organisational Wide Defaults (OWD) to make accounts Private so they can only be seen by the users in a particular branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Set Organization-Wide Defaults as Private for Accounts.
2) Define Sharing Rules based on your requirement.

Please refer help articles

> > [Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_sharing.htm&language=en)
> >
> > [Sharing Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_about_sharing_rules.htm&language=en)

**Trailhead** is awesome learning resource:
You should complete the trail for **Data Security** https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/data_security